# regular expression in ios to remove href links

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

i need some help in building a regular expression to remove href links with search terms from a long string that i then parse into a web view

an example of the href string : `<a href="/search/?search=Huntington">Huntington</a>`

i would like to remove everthing but the plain text of the link (just the link itself) but having troubles

```
 NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<a href=\"/search/?search=([A-Z][a-z])\"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

any help would be greatly welcomed

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<a href=\"[^\"]+\">([^<]+)</a>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"$1"];
```

should work (I tested the regexp in TextMate but not in XCode).

Comment: well, if you want to replace with juste the plain text of the link, you have to have a group between parenthesis somewhere

Comment: sry, wrong copy&paste regex, here is the correct one: "<a\shref=.*?>(.*?)<\/a>"

Comment: CarlJ's <a\shref=.*?>(.*?)<\/a> works, but should be @"<a href=.*?>(.*?)</a>" . Thanks a lot!

Comment: How would one go about making the plain text clickable? Because now the textview doesn't detect the links anymore

Answer (score 3):

@Helium3 and @Carl Explain right above and I want to write as corectly and I created this function for delete a href tag from NSString

```
-(NSString *)deleteAHref:(NSString *)originalString
{
    NSError *regexError = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<a href=.*?>(.*?)</a>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&regexError];
    NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:originalString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [originalString length]) withTemplate:@"$1"];
    return modifiedString;
}
```